# get a form array from a dynamic table

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a dynamic table which loads the data from my web api. So you can add a row and delete a row easily with buttons. Now my problem is, i dont know how i can get the values of every single row to save it into my web api. For example in my table are already the entries "male" and "female". Now i want to add with the table a new gender to my web api. I tried it with a FormArray and getRawValue. But everytime i log it in my console the whole array is empty, also there are not entries for my already existing values male and female.

My HTML:

```html
<div class="controlpanel">
    <div id="operatoren">
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary"(click)="addRow()" > <mat-icon color="white">  plus_one </mat-icon> </button>
        <a > Zurück</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="genderForm">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="genderDataSource" #genderTable >
        <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Speichern  <mat-icon color="primary"> save </mat-icon> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let anreden; "> 
            
            <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="saveRow()" > <mat-icon color="white">  save </mat-icon> </button>
            
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Löschen <mat-icon color="warn"> clear </mat-icon> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let anreden; let i = index"> 
            <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="delRow(i)" > <mat-icon color="white">  clear </mat-icon> </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="bezeichnung">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Bezeichnung </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let anreden; "> 
            <ng-container>
                <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                    <input matInput type="text" [value]='anreden.bezeichnung' formArrayName="anrede" name="anreden"> 
                </mat-form-field>
            </ng-container>       
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

My TS:

```html
export class AnredeKategorieComponent implements OnInit {

  public displayedColumns = ['edit', 'delete', 'bezeichnung'];
  public genderDataSource: any[];
  public anreden = [] as any;
  genderForm = new FormGroup({
    anrede: new FormArray([]),
  })
  constructor(
    public aService: AnredeVorschlägeService,
  ) { }
  @ViewChild('genderTable') table: MatTable<any>;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Alle Anreden
    this.aService.getAnrede()
    .subscribe(
      data => { 
        this.anreden = data;
        console.log(this.anreden);
        this.genderDataSource = data;
        this.getStandardValues();
    });
  }
  addRow(){
    let newCase = { bezeichnung: ''};
      this.genderDataSource.push(newCase);
      this.table.renderRows();
  }
  saveRow(){
    console.log(this.genderForm.getRawValue());
  }
  getStandardValues(){
    this.genderForm.patchValue({
      anrede: this.anreden
    })
  }
  delRow(i:any){
    this.genderDataSource.splice(i, 1);
    this.table.renderRows();
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like all your data is inside the genderDataSource. And not actually in the genderForm. Could you log what is inside the genderDataSoruce instead? I have feeling that's where your needed data is.

Comment: Yes genderDataSource is where my data is. But how can i push new dynamic data to it? I mean the input of my new row should be pushed to it. Currently its bezeichnung: ''.  I think i need to add the form array here.

Comment: Well this means you don't need the other array, but that you could just map the data from the genderDataSource and post that.